# Run Laravel artisan composer scripts after Heroku Deploy

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, deployment, laravel-artisan

I wanted to know whether there is any way to run some Laravel artisan scripts via Composer as soon as it has been deployed to Heroku. I want to run the following script:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Is there a way to do so with Composer and not the Heroku release phases?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) for this.

According to the [Heroku Build behavior](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#build-behavior) `composer install` is run during the deployment so you could add a custom command to the [post-install-cmd](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events) event.

In your composer.json you could add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

The command would be run after the install command has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

As [Remul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57756825/4464398) answer you can use compose scripts for this purpose but for the Heroku or other buildpack systems you have to use ["compile" script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#custom-compile-step) instead of "post-install-cmd" event.

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
}
```

The command would be run after the install command has been executed.
Ref: [Custom compile step on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#custom-compile-step)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your hosting supports ssh, then download this application bvsshClient, login to you ftp using your details and it would open a cmd window for you to perform any operation. But you might not have access root access to install applications

Comment: (a) This won't work as expected on Heroku (which has an ephemeral filesystem). (b) OP asked for an _automated_ solution. Why are you suggesting a purely manual one?